# share component between pages without reloading it

Tags: javascript, refresh

Do any of you know how can I share a component between several html pages but load it only once?

I`m trying to share a unit canvas between several pages, but it takes too long to load, so every time I change the page it loads again, causing a very poor user experience. I tried to create the frame once and put it on session to be reused, but it seem to be not the fix for it.

I need to use the same component amongst all the pages without reloading it every time the user changes the browser address.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share some code? How much of the page is your canvas? Could you reload other elements around it?

Comment: I am sorry about not giving the code, cause it is under NDA. We can consider that the host pages (the one containing the canvas) will be dynamic ones, being able to change and they can insert the canvas component in any position at any time, setting it visible or not. It should behave like a static java class for example, where all the classes share the same information, in this case, the loaded canvas .

Answer (score 1):

we had the same problem with adding the communicator to out online app (something like on FB). The best solution is to do a single page application and manage urls by html5 history API, but is only applicable when you start development. You could also try something with iframe e.g. put canvas in main document and the rest (changing part) in iframe, but you will have a problem with urls, so it isn't solution.
Becouse we had working app when we started work on communicator we ended up with everything store in session like you did.

Comment: Im using frame now, but it does not avoid the unit to reload as it will be placed in a already done website. we can`t change the website and the most we can do is offer the unity as a "component" that they can call and use and that the hardest part, because even if we decide to use single page frameworks it will not be useful for them, as they still change pages in the old fashioned way.  thank you for the tips.